# Immediately after login, my 12.04 LTS desktop asks for my password for "Authentication is required to change user data"

Tags: 12.04, login, authentication, users

I have two Ubuntu 12.04 systems, one a desktop, and the other running as a NIS/NFS server (a desktop with lightdm disabled). When I login, I get the dialog (not error) "Authentication is required to change user data" The Details section of the dialog says "org.freedesktop.accounts.user-administration"

Any help helping me figure out how to make this dialog go away is appreciated.

BTW, not entering the password has no effect whatsoever.

Comment: Could you solve this problem? I have the same issue on a range of machines authenticating via Active Directory (centrify).

Comment: @uzhoasit: Sorry, no luck yet. I am not sure what the problem is, still.

Comment: Seems to be an issue with Unity. I try to fix it with support from Canonical. I'll post back the results.

Comment: How do you authenticate your users? Normal local users with local passwords?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the usernames (local:bob, network:bob) to have the same UID.  You would likely want to change the local account as opposed to the network one.

In my setup:
I ran id bob to get the AD/network UID.
Then I edited /etc/passwd and changed the UID of the local bob account.  (This can be dangerous, if you mess up!)

If you have a graphical environment go to Users and Groups -> Click on the user account in question, Advanced Settings, and then change the UID there.

The indicator-applet issue will not be fixed in Ubuntu (even though it is caused by an Ubuntu specific patch): You can see more details here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-messages/+bug/1192300

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be an issue with messaging indicator.

As an intermediate solution you can remove the messaging indicator with `sudo apt-get remove indicator-messages`

Comment: Though this was the solution I adopted, the reply due to gQuigs below gave me a better picture of why. I hope you don't mind me selecting the answer due to gQuigs.

Comment: @Sonny: The solution from qQuigs is the official one. So its ok to select it as solution.