# What service asks for "Authentication to change own user data"?

Tags: permissions, process

Related: [Seemingly random “Authentication is required to change your own user data”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/562355/seemingly-random-authentication-is-required-to-change-your-own-user-data/)

Every now and then (**only** after resuming from *Suspend*) I get the following dialogue.

[image]

The information provided is not enough for me to decide what to do (hence I *cancel* of course :-)
The link in the Details section leads nowhere.

My guess is that there is some program (A) asking some service (B) for permissions.

I want to know how to find out what service/program (B) generates this dialogue (hints about the program (A) requesting the permissions in the first place are welcome too :-))

Ubuntu 15.10

Further investigation spurred by waltinator's answer shows `polkitd` to possibly be part (B)

Excerpt from `journalctl` (linebreaks inserted to prevent scrolling)

> ```
> Jan 10 12:22:04 big polkitd(authority=local)[1157]: Operator of unix-session:c2  
>    FAILED to authenticate to gain authorization for action  
>    org.freedesktop.accounts.change-own-user-data  
>    for system-bus-name::1.68  
>    [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-messages/indicator-messages-service]  
>    (owned by unix-user:g)
> Jan 10 12:22:04 big dbus[1045]: [system] Rejected send message, 9 matched rules;  
>    type="error", sender=":1.4"  
>    (uid=0 pid=1117 comm="/usr/lib/accountsservice/accounts-daemon ")  
>    interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error  
>    name="org.freedesktop.Accounts.Error.PermissionDenied"  
>    requested_reply="0" destination=":1.68"  
>    (uid=1000 pid=3973 comm="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-messages/indic")
> ```

Thanks to waltinator's suggestion about `xwininfo` (which doesn't tell the pid of the window's process) I now found `wininfo`. So I was able to confirm that the window is created by `/usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1`.

Now I want a way to ask `polkitd`/`policykit` which program requested which action, but that needs a new question.

Comment: Looks very much like a result of https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/policykit-1-gnome/+bug/1512002, but I don't want to close the question as long as the connection is not confirmed.

Comment: It is confirmed, and now fixed

Answer (score 4):

`xlsclients` will help you find out which process owns the popup. From `man xlsclients` (actually from http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/xlsclients.1.html):

trusty (1) xlsclients.1.gz
Provided by: x11-utils_7.7+1_i386 bug

NAME

```
   xlsclients - list client applications running on a display
```

SYNOPSIS

```
   xlsclients [-display displayname] [-a] [-l] [-m maxcmdlen]
```

DESCRIPTION

```
   Xlsclients  is  a  utility  for  listing  information  about the client
   applications running on a display.  It may be used to generate  scripts
   representing a snapshot of the user's current session.


NAME

       xlsclients - list client applications running on a display

SYNOPSIS

       xlsclients [-display displayname] [-a] [-l] [-m maxcmdlen]
```

Comment: `xlsclients` is a nice find, thank you, the problem I face now is that the output of `xlsclients -al` is the same when the dialogue is on screen and after I have it closed. Next time I'm gonna try with root permissions.

Comment: `xwininfo` may help.

Answer (score 1):

This bug has been resolved: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/policykit-1-gnome/+bug/1512002

You can install the updated package (must enable 'proposed' repo) which modifies the policy:

```
/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.accounts.policy
- <allow_any>auth_self</allow_any>
- <allow_inactive>auth_self</allow_inactive>
+ <allow_any>yes</allow_any>
+ <allow_inactive>yes</allow_inactive>
```

> "Currently, data/org.freedesktop.accounts.policy.in specifies that a user must be active in order to set his own data." -alkisg
>
> "I can't think of any reason why having a session would be important in this case, so I think changing allow_any to yes should be fine." -mdeslaur
>
> "This bug was fixed in the package accountsservice - 0.6.40-2ubuntu12" -[janitor](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/policykit-1-gnome/+bug/1512002/comments/46)